# Javascript / Html Check box error

Tags: javascript, html

So, I started this project for school; I'm a beginner in javascript as you can see from the code, and I'm kinda stuck. First of all, I want to make a quiz where you have to introduce the amount of questions you want to answer, then answer them ofc. For the beginning I chose 7 questions with random answers to test it. The problem is that when I introduce 3 or less questions to answer it works fine, but when i go for more (+3 <=7) I get a strange error: index.html?fname=3:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined(…). Here is my code:

[My code](http://pastebin.com/3g3Y5vEz)

Im sorry for distrubing you with my stupidity! Have a nice day!
PS: I forgot to mention that this code isnt finished (I still need to style it), so dont judge me.

Comment: Hello Ciocirlan, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a snippet of relevant codes along with your question. Codes in external links might expire thus rendering the thread useless for other Stack users having a similar issue. Cheers

Comment: I just started to use Stack and I know , my bad .I am going to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 68 of your code, you set `y` to be the number of questions the user asked for.

```
y=document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
```

This loop (starting on line 102) is where the error is coming from:

```
for(var i=0; i<y; i++){
    if(choices[i].checked){
        choice = choices[i].value;
    }
}
```

Here's what happens: If you ask for 4 questions, this loop will keep running as long as `i` is less than 4. When `i` is 3, the `if` statement will be trying to access `choices[3].checked`. Remember, `choices[3]` is actually the 4th item in the array since indexes start at 0. Each question only has 3 choices, so when you ask for the 4th one you get `undefined`.

But you want this loop to look at 3 and only 3 answers for each question, regardless of how many questions there are in total. What you probably meant to write was this:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(choices[i].checked){
        choice = choices[i].value;
    }
}
```